# Observable array and computed error

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have a list of checkboxes that execute functions on check and uncheck. I also have an observable array that holds the values of the checkboxes currently active (put into local storage). The relevant code is here:

```
this.layerToggleChecked = knockout.observableArray();

// ...

this.layerToggle = function (source, name, type, url, description) {
    return knockout.computed({
        read: function () {
            return this.layerToggleChecked();
        },
        write: function (checked) {
            if (checked) {
                alert("loading");
                this.layerToggleChecked.push(source());
            } else {
                alert("removing");
                this.layerToggleChecked.remove(source());
            }
        }
    }, this);
}
```

The checkboxes work as planned triggering the functions until I added `return this.layerToggleChecked();` which returns

> knockout-3.2.0.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: b.push is not a function

Comment: It's unclear what's triggering the error. Please replicate it in an [MCVE](/help/mcve) using Stack Snippets (the `<>` button in the toolbar).

Comment: Its also not toally clear what you're expecting to happen by returning a computed observable from a function which is, presumably, executed on click of a checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knockout's `checked` binding handles arrays differently from other values. You're expecting a `true` or `false` to be written to the computed observable, but you're returning an array, which obviously aren't the same.

From http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html:

> Special consideration is given if your parameter resolves to an `array`. In this case, KO will set the element to be checked if the value matches an item in the array, and unchecked if it is not contained in the array.
>
> When the user checks or unchecks the checkbox, KO will add or remove the value from the array accordingly.

Since you're using an array to hold the checked values, you're better off binding directly to it:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: source, checked: layerToggleChecked" />
```